# Center absolute UL's LI

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to center the dots on my absolute UL. I've had a lot of trouble after trying lots of different answers around the web.

Here's the CSS (.new-dots is the UL):

```
.photos {
    .new-dots {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      text-align: center;

      li {
        display: inline;
        color: rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.78);
        margin-right: 5px;

        button {
          background: rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.75);
          border-width: 0;
          width: 16px;
          height: 16px;
          border-radius: 8px;
          color: transparent;
        }

        button:focus {
          outline: none;
        }
      }

      .slick-active {
        button {
          background: #FFF !important;
        }
      }
    }

    .photo {
      height: 100vw;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please add relevant HTML and clarify the desired result with an image for example. What have you tried so far and what did it produce?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the elemet and it will center the child element inside the parent element.

Code Example

```css
body {
position: relative;
height: 100vh;
}

.new-dots {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="new-dots">Test Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- change to `display: inline-block;` in `li` from `display: inline;`.
- By default `ul` have their own `padding` and `margin`, so you need
  to remove that. in your case, you have to set `padding-left: 0`.
- In addition, you can also remove `width: 100%` from the `ul` and set
  `left` and `right` to `0` so that it occupy it's parents full width.

```css
.photos .new-dots {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.photos .new-dots li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.78);
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.photos .new-dots li button {
  background: rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.75);
  border-width: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: transparent;
}
.photos .new-dots li button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.photos .new-dots .slick-active button {
  background: #fff !important;
}
.photos .photo {
  height: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="photos">
  <ul class="new-dots">
    <li><button>123</button></li>
    <li><button>456</button></li>
    <li><button>789</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

working pen [here](https://codepen.io/arpanpatel/pen/GddzeV)

Comment: if this answer helped you, please accept and upvote the answer :)